# How can I treat inputs from the command line in ASM as numbers instead of characters

Tags: assembly, tasm

I want to return the square of a number that will be given to me in the command line. However I have not found out how to treat the input from the command line as a number instead of a string

Comment: This is assembly language; if you want any kind of conversion to happen you have to write instructions to make it happen.  See also the [FAQ section of the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 0):

The command line options are given to you as a character string. If you want to treat them as numbers, you have to [parse them yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471281/how-to-convert-string-to-number-in-tasm?noredirect=1&lq=1).